# react substracts characters of input value

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation

hello i am creating react-validation, i got stuck and i don't know what is causing the bug, so  my code is this

```
class Form extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirm_password: '',
    errorBol: false,
    errorMessage: ''
    }

    this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)
    this.handlePcChange = this.handlePcChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)

}

 handleUsernameChange(e){
    if(this.state.username.trim().length < 6){
        this.setState({
            errorBol: true,
            errorMessage: 'username character length must be at least 6 character'
        })                   
   }
   if(this.state.username.trim().length > 6){
    this.setState({
        errorBol: false,

    })                   
}

    this.setState({
        username: e.target.value
    })
}
handleEmailChange(e){

    if(this.state.email.trim().length < 1){
        this.setState({
            errorBol: true,
            errorMessage: 'please fill email field'
        })                  

   }
   if(this.state.email.trim().length > 1){
    this.setState({
        errorBol: false,

    })                  

}

    this.setState({
        email: e.target.value
    })
}
handlePasswordChange(e){
    if(this.state.password.trim().length < 8){
        this.setState({
            errorBol: true,
            errorMessage: 'password character length must be at least 8 character'
          })  


          }
            else{
                this.setState({
                    errorBol: false,
                                       })
            }
   for(let c = 0; c <= this.state.password.length; c++){
       if(this.state.password.charAt(c) !== this.state.password.charAt(c).toUpperCase()){
           this.setState({
               errorBol:true,
               errorMessage: 'at least one character of password must be capital'
           })
       }
       else{
        this.setState({
            errorBol: false,

        })
       }

   }
   for(let c = 0; c <= this.state.password.length; c++){
    if(this.state.password.charAt(c) !== this.state.password.charAt(c).toLowerCase()){
           this.setState({
          errorBol:true,
          errorMessage: 'one character of password must be lower case'
                        })
    }
    else{
        this.setState({
            errorBol: false,

        })
    }

 } 


   let containsNumber = /\d/.test(this.state.password)
   if(containsNumber === false){
       this.setState({
           errorBol: true,
           errorMessage: 'password must contain at least one number'
       })

   }else{
    this.setState({
        errorBol: false,

    })
   }



    this.setState({

        password: e.target.value
    })

}
handlePcChange(e){
    if(this.state.password !== this.state.confirm_password){
        this.setState({
            errorBol: true,
            errorMessage: 'პაროლები არ ემთხვევა'
        })
    }
    if(this.state.password === this.state.confirm_password){
    this.setState({
        errorBol: false,

    })
}
    this.setState({

        confirm_password: e.target.value
    })
}
handleFormSubmit(e){

    e.preventDefault();
   alert('hey')


}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <form id="formID" className="fc" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.username} placeholder="username"  autoComplete = "off" name="username" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}/><br/>
                <input type="email" placeholder="email" value={this.state.email}  autoComplete = "off" name="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/><br/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" value={this.state.password}  autoComplete = "off" name="password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}/><br/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="confirm passowrd"  autoComplete = "off" value={this.state.confirm_password} name="password_confirmation" onChange={this.handlePcChange}/><br/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                {this.state.errorBol === true ? this.state.errorMessage : null }
            </form>
        </div>
    )
 }
}
```

and the bug: when i enter 6 character in username input it still shows error message but when i enter 8 character it disappears also when i have 8 character and delete 3 character (and input currently has 5 character which must cause error according to code) it does nothing but when i delete 4 it shows me that input must have at least 6 char  i tried it also in email input and it did the same when i entered more than 1 char it still showed me error message but when i entered 3 character it disappeared, then i changed username character length from 6 to 4 and it worked when i entered 6 character
so i do not how but it substracts 2 character, also password validation is weird too, it accepts one lowercase character then one number and one character again only if number is between and things like that, password confirmation does not works also, this is messy code and if anyone has clue i will be glad to hear it, you can test this code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

as a matter of fact if it changes anything this is Form subcomponent for Sign Up component and is exported in parent component

THANK YOU

Comment: your error validation check is looking at `this.state.username` so its always checking the last inputed username after you type something, i would recommend adapting the code to follow something like user enters input -> pass it into a function that validates it and return a bool `isValid`, and perhaps an error message, base on what that functions returns, then use an if/else to update state

Comment: why would you recommending this can you explain me cause of the bug in details?

Comment: the user is inputting a value into the form -> `e.target.value`, but when you run `if(this.state.username.trim().length < 6){` `this.state.username` is not `e.target.value`, it is the value they entered before entering the current value, you should check `e.target.value` before persisting it to the store.

Comment: so if i change `if(this.state.username.trim().length < 6){` to `if(e.target.value.trim().length < 6){`   it will work?

Comment: it will work better, but there are many other bugs with this similar logic, you need to go thru the execution and fix, use some `debugger` statements or `console.log`s to check what the code is doing and it will better help you debug.  You are pretty close to getting it to work tho

Comment: what other bugs you see there, thank you by the way

Comment: by the way i tried e.target.value in case of email it works but in case of username it now substracts 1 character. and what can i say about password it is still buggy but password confirmation works

Comment: the loop statements to check if there is a capital or lowercase letter are updating state every index change so basically its only checking the last letter, you should consider a different approach, you can look up how to use `regex` to test for a lowercase letter and use the `.test` method to better implement

Comment: email and password is also looking at state and not the value that was entered like with username

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation has some issues.

### Issues

In each `handleChange()` `this.state` is **NOT** holding the values that contain the **UPDATED** values. `e.target.value` is containing the updated text, so use it.

Also, you're using a single state variable to indicate whether form is valid or not. This will fail because if user types in correct username and others are empty, you'll still get valid form. This is wrong.

Also, writing a function for each text field is a pain.

### Suggestions

Use a single function to handle user input changes. Make use of `name` attribute you provided with the `<input>` elements.

Use a validity state for every field. Then allow submission if all are valid.

Have a look at this solution

### Solution

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      username_valid: false,
      email: '',
      email_valid: false,
      password: '',
      password_valid: false,
      confirm_password: '',
      confirm_password_valid: false,
      errorMessage: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const field = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value.trim();

    let errMsg = '';

    switch (field) {
      case 'username':
        errMsg = value.length < 6 ? 'Username must be 6 char or more' : '';
        break;
      case 'email':
        errMsg = value.length < 1 ? 'Please fill up email' : '';
        break;
      case 'password':
        if (value.length < 8) {
          errMsg = 'Password must be 8 char or more';
        } else {
          let test = (/[a-z]/.test(value) ? true : false)
                    && (/[A-Z]/.test(value) ? true : false)
                    && (/\d/.test(value) ? true : false);
          errMsg = test ? '' : 'Password must contain a lowercase, an auppercase and a digit';
        }
        if (value === this.state.confirm_password) {
          this.setState({ confirm_password_valid: true });
        } else {
          this.setState({ confirm_password_valid: false });
        }
        break;
      case 'confirm_password':
        errMsg = value !== this.state.password ? 'Both passwords must match' : '';
        break;
      default:

    }

    this.setState({
      [field]: value,
      [field + '_valid']: errMsg === '' ? true : false,
      errorMessage: errMsg
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { username_valid, email_valid, password_valid, confirm_password_valid } = this.state;
    if (username_valid && email_valid && password_valid && confirm_password_valid) {
      alert("Form submitted!");
    }
    console.log(username_valid, email_valid, password_valid, confirm_password_valid);
  }

  render() {
    const { username, email, password, confirm_password } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value={username} autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="you@example.com" value={email} autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value={password} autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
          <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="password" value={confirm_password} autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button><br />
          <label>{this.state.errorMessage}</label>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**NOTE**: If your form is very simple, you can just use **uncontrolled inputs**. Just google *Uncontrolled inputs in react* you'll find.

**NOTE**: If you're new to any of these syntax, try googling *ES6 features*. One of them is *object destructuring. I'm assuming you won't have any issues with the syntax.